# Nothing happening after login

Tags: system-installation

I got an old windows eMachine that was given to me by a friend and I tried installing Ubuntu off of a USB drive.

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2 and installed it to a USB, out it into the computer and selected the option to install it to the hard drive and wipe all the old data so there was nothing else on the hard drive. When it boots up I get to the login screen and after I type in my password I just get the orange Ubuntu screen and nothing else.

I let it sit for a few minutes and eventually I'll just get diagonal lines that appear across the screen. I'm really really new to Linux and planned on using this computer as a media center for my TV.

Anybody know what I can do to fix this? Try to be as simplistic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by that `old` word you've mentioned, I'm quite sure that this is the problem with your hardware, as in, it's not good enough to support Unity (the Ubuntu's default Desktop Environment).

Now I have to suggest you to look into [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) to install something a bit more lightweight.

Unfortunately, I can't be any more precise with my answer because I don't currently know your system specifications. If you edit your question and be a bit more precise, I will edit my answer appropriately.